# What to do with the [whisker] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

There are currently 10 questions with the [whisker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whisker) tag. 8 of the questions are about the whiskers on a boxplot, but 2 of them refer to an R package called 'whisker'. The current tag description refers to the whiskers on a boxplot, but that's because I suggested the description a few weeks ago, without realizing there is an R package called ['whisker'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/whisker/index.html).

Personally, I think it would make sense to change the description to match the R package and possibly rename it to [whisker-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whisker-package) to make the tag clearer. I don't think it's necessary to have a separate tag to refer to the whiskers on a boxplot, those would be covered by the [boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boxplot) tag.

How should this situation be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The evidence suggests that the "whisker" term is ambiguous. As such, it needs to be disambiguated:

- The R package to [r-whisker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-whisker)
- The plot detail to [box-and-whisker-plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-and-whisker-plot), a synonym to [boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boxplot) ([both are official terms for the plot type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot)).

Comment: Would it be helpful to remove the original `whisker` tag then?

Comment: @HS-nebula It will be removed automatically at the end of the day when there are no more questions with it.